# Dynamically add reference of OData service in multiple projects

Tags: c#, wcf, odata

I have a similar situation like here:
[Dynamically add reference of WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612387/dynamically-add-reference-of-wcf-service)

However, there is one class library, which references a WCF service - let's call it CL1.
Then there are multiple projects - let's call them P1 and P2 - which reference to CL1.

How it looks like now:
There are two versions of CL1, just because I don't know how to dynamically add a wcf service reference.
So it looks like this:

> P1 uses CL1 Version 1.
>
> P2 uses CL1 Version 2.

However, I would rather inject the URL of the service from PL1 and PL2 into CL1. So I don't have to maintain two versions!

So it should rather look like this:

### Goal

> P1 and P2 inject Service-URL into CL1. CL1 adds or updates the service reference (generate reference.cs and rebuilds itself).

Any ideas of how I could achieve this? Or may there be better approaches?

Comment: CL1 and CL2 are two separate ClassLibrary-projects with the same content that just differ in their app.configs?

Comment: @khlr The reference.cs also varies (The meta-data from the service reference are different). Everything else is the same.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036308/dynamically-switch-wcf-web-service-reference-url-path-through-config-file) may already do the trick for you (can't say for sure, as you've not yet posted any relevant code). Apart from that you could dynamically create your proxy using the [ChannelFactory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms576132.aspx).